# Why are editor Apps Script executions different from trigger executions?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, google-apps-script

Have found nothing online on this:

I have built a script that repeatedly populates a sheet before copying it to a separate spreadsheet. The issue is my script behaves differently if executed from the editor versus when triggered from inside the spreadsheet.

When run from the Apps Script editor, the script runs as expected whereas when run from a custom menu item or a trigger in an embedded photo, my function populating my original sheet doesn't have a chance to finish execution before it is copied to a separate spreadsheet.

When executed from a trigger, my separate spreadsheet's copied sheet resembles my original sheet mid-execution. It gets copied before the function populating the original sheet is done executing. This is a problem since my code is meant for another person to use it directly from the spreadsheet.

edit (here's the code):

```
//loop thru supervisor, create new page
for (let i = 0; i < swConcise.length; i++){

let swName = swConcise[i];

//draw social worker report function
batchSocialWorker(swName);

//copy to alt ss
const sheet = baseSS.getSheetByName('SocialWorkersReport');
sheet.copyTo(newSS);

//rename sheet
newSS.getSheets()[i+1].setName(swName);

}
```

Edit (longer code if you need):

```
function batchSocialWorkers(){

/*
1. create new ss, set baseSS, newSS vars
2. create directors array
3. loop directors, copy sheet to newSS and rename
4. create link in new sheet
*/

const baseSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//create new ss titled date, sw Report
const today = date();

const title = "Social Workers Reports " + today;

const id = createSS (title);
const newSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);

//scrape social workers names
const swAll = baseSS.getSheetByName('Relationships').getRange('F11:F').getValues();

//create concise s0cial workers array
const swConcise = cleanupArray(swAll);

//loop thru supervisor, create new page
for (let i = 0; i < swConcise.length; i++){

let swName = swConcise[i];

//draw social worker report function
batchSocialWorker(swName);

//copy to alt ss
const sheet = baseSS.getSheetByName('SocialWorkersReport');
sheet.copyTo(newSS);

//rename sheet
newSS.getSheets()[i+1].setName(swName);

}  

//delete first 2 sheets
newSS.deleteSheet(newSS.getSheets()[0]);
newSS.deleteSheet(newSS.getSheets()[0]);

//provide link to new sheet
const link = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + id;
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.alert('Batch Social Workers Reports Created', link, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}

function createSS (title) {
// This code uses the Sheets Advanced Service, but for most use cases
// the built-in method SpreadsheetApp.create() is more appropriate.
try {
let sheet = Sheets.newSpreadsheet();
sheet.properties = Sheets.newSpreadsheetProperties();
sheet.properties.title = title;
const spreadsheet = Sheets.Spreadsheets.create(sheet);

return spreadsheet.spreadsheetId;
} catch (err) {
// TODO (developer) - Handle exception
console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
}
}

function cleanupArray (array){

let newArray = new Array();

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

if (array[i][0] != '') newArray.push(array[i][0]);

}

return newArray;
}
```

Comment: The trigger provides and event object that the code may be using.   You would have to supply more details to completely understand your issue.  Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I am not using an event object. Which details do you need? I've added my relevant code.

Comment: I need to see the code and understand how it's being called

Comment: I need to see the complete function definition

Comment: If you have parameters in your function then they are being replace by the trigger event object even if you supply default parameters

Comment: @cooper I added the inclusive function in latest edit.

Comment: What function did you call with the trigger?

Comment: I don't believe you need to see any code to answer my question. The function being triggered is batchSocialWorkers(). The first example is simply an excerpt of the second example. There are no differences.

Comment: I saw enough in what you provide to see that there are several errors in the code.  Take a look at my answer and from that I think with your help we can arrive at a working solution.

Comment: Can you share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet so we can replicate the issue. Remove sensitive data if any.

Answer (score 0):

This is partly a guess because you have not provided all of the code:

But try this.  I still don't know which functions you are calling by a trigger.  But I did see several errors in your code.  I tried to repair what I can.

```
function batchSocialWorkers() {
  const bss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const title = "Social Workers Reports " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),bss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy");//guess at the format
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(title);
  const sh = bss.getSheetByName('Relationships')
  const vs = sh.getRange('F11:F' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    let swName = vs[i];
    batchSocialWorker(swName);
    const sheet = bss.getSheetByName('SocialWorkersReport');
    sheet.copyTo(ss);
    ss.getSheets()[i + 1].setName(swName);
  }
  ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
  ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
  const link = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + id;
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Batch Social Workers Reports Created', link, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

Comment: My original code ran perfectly when invoked from the editor. It had aforementioned issues when invoked from a trigger within spreadsheet. You have made various changes to my code. How exactly did you solve the issue?

Comment: Does it run now?